# How to create editor for database view (with joins) in Windows Forms/WPF?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

What would be the simplest way to create a quick editor for some data in the database in WPF/WinForms, where the data is represented by a View in the SQL Server database?

Say I have a table `Person { id int, name nvarchar(max), GenderID int, CityID int}`, where GenderID and CityID is a reference into tables Gender and City. In the editor, the Person would appear as textbox for name, combobox for gender (selecting names of the genders from Gender table) and the same for the city column.

Is there something easy that I can do so some control/code would generate this? If I'd like to only select data, then WinForms DataGridView or WPF DataGrid can generate a column for each property, and show a row for each object in a collection. -

Is there some kind of similar magic control, that could do this for a database view, if the relations are defined by a foreign key?

It seems to me that thousands of developers have faced this kind of problem - to quickly create a GUI for editing database rows with relationships to other tables, so there should be some kind of universally accepted solution. Or is everyone doing this in the code? Or, if there is a tool for this in other language, not C#, not Windows Forms - like dBase.

Comment: are you aware of the DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns Property? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx). It does a lot of things automatically, and you can customize it somehow overriding the DataGridView.

Comment: I am, and it works fine for browsing the data, but it doesn't solve a problem for editing data

Comment: I believe it should support editing as well, provided it "thinks" your datasource is editable. Please explain in your question what kind of datasource do you provide.

Comment: What's your data access layer? If you're using Entity Framework you can map the views for the select, and the Insert/Update/Delete to stored proc's which allow you to control how the underlying tables get updated.

Comment: That is better, but is there no way to avoid writing stored procedures for insert/update/delete commands, if the view is simple select from one table with inner joins to some other tables?

Comment: FYI, SQL Server itself doesn't allow executing an UPDATE on a View if it fetches data from more than one table.

Comment: Of course, but for doing primitive inner joins to some other table (1:many or 1:1 relation), there might exist some software/tool that shows stuffs from joined tables in comboboxes, remembers its IDs and uses them on UPDATE of original table.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing what is known as scaffolding in web development. Scaffolding is a way to automatically generate UIs for each table in the database. Scaffolding lets you create a functional UI for viewing and editing data based on the schema of the data. Here are a couple of resources for WPF scaffolding.

1. There is a WPF scaffolding article on the Code Project website: [WPF CRUD Generator (Scaffolding)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36975/WPF-CRUD-Generator-Scaffolding)
2. There is also a Codeplex project that could be helpful: [WPF Scaffolder](http://wpfscaffolder.codeplex.com)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

ASP .NET Dynamic Data uses templates to auto-generate a UI for you that will represent the database tables/views you choose, including the auto-generated CRUD capabilities you want.

It even gets the lookup tables right and renders dropdowns automatically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845452(v=vs.100).aspx