# How to create a module for showing tables with SqlServer query designer capabilities

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, diagram

I am currently deploying a query builder in C#. I want to know how can I create a  module for showing a table in a query like the SqlServer query designer. In fact I want to be able to drag a table from my tree list to the diagram, so that users can join tables with drag and drop by fields. The desired behaviour is exactly like in the SqlServer query designer.

See this picture http://barnamenevis.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=120666&d=1404234042

My goal is to create a red border module.

Comment: Can you tell which UI do you use? WinForms or WPF?

Comment: windows form but wpf is ok too

Comment: Well, your question is a bit too broad for the format of this site. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581047/how-to-create-editor-for-database-view-with-joins-in-windows-forms-wpf) deals with similar problems and have few interesting links that I hope may help you. Otherwise try to search for some examples on codeproject and other resources.